# Is it possible to create a VS Code theme extension using JavaScript or TypeScript instead JSON?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating a theme extension for vs code. And I wanted to know, if it's possible to use JavaScript or TypeScript files instead of a JSON file. I don't like that the whole theme is inside one huge JSON file. I find it very messy and complicated to handle. And also, it does not accept comments.

Comment: how would you write this more compact using JavaScript, you just assign colors to theme-names

Comment: @rioV8 they didn't say anything about finding problems with compactness or concision.

Comment: @starball he speaks about `huge` file, so he has an idea that will make it smaller by using JS or TS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the theme definition file needs to be in JSON format (see also https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#create-a-new-color-theme).

> I don't like that the whole theme is inside one huge JSON file. I find it very messy and complicated to handle. And also, it does not accept comments.

Then you can write a script / scripts that *produce* the final JSON file. There are several theme extensions that do this. There are other benefits to doing this, including then being able to do calculations to produce modified versions of colours, such as defining one colour in terms of modifications on another colour.